# Can I use an easy programming language with XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, programming

TeX is frustrating me. It has only the basics - and even then, I have to search how to divide two numbers.

The question is this: can I write my macros in more convenient language like Ruby or Lisp?

UPD: I will explain my situation. I'm writing a rulebook for my RPG module, and I need to construct an equipment table. Problem is, my rules are not the simplest ones:

http://pastebin.com/Z4Q9TQa5

I want nice fonts, so I use XeLaTeX. I am Russian, so I need polyglossia or babel.

Please note that every suggestion is tested against **XeLaTeX,** not LaTeX.

Comment: Broad answer 'no', but look at LaTeX3's `expl3` language as a richer set of tools built on top of TeX.

Comment: Or switch to LuaTeX and use lua.

Comment: May you show an example of a situation in which such programming features are needed?

Comment: See also: [question about Python in particular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598403/can-i-execute-python-code-inside-latex), lt3luabridge (execute Lua code from PDFLaTeX), ctan topic https://ctan.org/topic/callback and https://ctan.org/topic/exec-foreign. There's also Rmarkdown/knitr (preprocess generate LaTeX code) although I don't use them  myself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package is another Python-based option.  PythonTeX was primarily developed for mathematical and scientific applications, but it's also suitable for much general-purpose work. I've included a few basic examples of creating macros with PythonTeX below.  You do have to be careful about catcodes if you are working with special characters.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

Basic math:  \py{5324/251}

Macros that more closely interact with TeX:

\newcommand{\reverse}[1]{\py{"#1"[::-1]}}

\reverse{A sentence!}

\newcommand{\listtotabular}[1]{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \py{'&'.join("#1".split(','))} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
}

\listtotabular{First, Second, Third, Fourth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition to the examples above, and the examples included with the documentation, you might also look at the following examples.

- [Plotting the derivative of a function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73920/get-derivative-of-a-function)
- [Using Python to create tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65290/embedding-python-in-tikz)
- [Solving an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67532/iterative-method-to-solve-nonlinear-equations)

Comment: It's very buggy. Did you know that 'newfloat' package is actially distributed as 'caption'? I couldn't run the example, some obscure pgf error (pgfopts is installed) about /PYTX.

Comment: I'd overlooked that you need XeLaTeX.  The example above works with XeLaTeX (at least with Windows with a fresh TeX Live 2012 installation).  But the example file from GitHub won't work, unless you remove the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages, load `fontspec` and use `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}`, and run xelatex with the `-8bit` option.  The `-8bit` option is  needed for handling tabs; see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/how-to-output-a-tabulation-into-a-file).

Comment: Thanks; it gave me a mountain of errors, but worked. Seems like it needs strict TL2012.

Answer (score 11):

- Python: [package python](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/python.html), [example](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/)
- Perl: [PerlTeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/perltex.html), [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/perltex/perltex.pdf)
- (LuaTeX: [reference](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/luatex/base/manual/luatexref-t.pdf), [documentation for LuaLaTeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf)) (not for XeTeX)

Comment: PerlTeX is not working with XeTeX, and LuaLaTeX has known issues with non-Latin languages.

I couldn't start python package, it gives a "can't find file `test.py.out'." error, but I'll keep digging that way.

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't tried, you might be able to use [`bashful`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bashful) to interact with programs written in other languages via stdin and stdout.

I had no problems with a simple example as long as I compiled with `-shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\def\fortune{\splice{fortune}}
\begin{document}
\fortune

\fortune
\end{document}
```

I am not sure about the `polyglossia` issue that is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Seems like it hacks Polyglossia, causing it to use latin monospaced font. Also gives me an error because "File test.stdout was empty"

Comment: @AlexanderYakovlev I could get a simple example running no problem

Answer (score 2):

Now you can try [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package. It provides a LaTeX2 interface for `expl3` and you can do functional programming similar to other modern programming languages such as `Lua`. The evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside.

Here is a simple example showing the similarity between `functional` code and `lua` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}

%% Functional code for comparison

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MathSquare { m } {
  \IntSet \lTmpaInt { \IntEval {#1 * #1} }
  \Result { \Value \lTmpaInt }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\MathSquare{5}
\MathSquare{\MathSquare{5}}

\end{document}
```

```lua
-- Lua code for comparison --

-- define a function --
function MathSquare (arg)
  local lTmpaInt = arg * arg
  return lTmpaInt
end
-- use the function --
print(MathSquare(5))
print(MathSquare(MathSquare(5)))
```

Note that with this package, you need to pass return values of functions with `\Result` command.